# curl (3) <url> malformed while accessing file from smb to local on mac

Tags: macos, curl, libcurl, smb

Trying to run following command from terminal on mac machine to access dmg file from smb server

```
curl -u "domain\username:password" smb://a/b/c/d.dmg' /Users/username/Desktop/mntpoint/'

hdiutil attach '/Users/username/Desktop/mntpnt'

cp -r '/Volumes/filename' '/Users/$USER/Applications'
```

After executing first line of code i am able to see many data is downloading on terminal but then it shows 
 `curl (3) <url> malformed`

So after that if i try to run hdiutil attach command it shows invalid image format